# OpenCL OpenGL interop and Element buffer

Tags: opengl, opencl

I created an OpenGL element buffer to draw a set of triangles.
When I try to use this buffer in an OpenCL kernel, the values in the array are shifted.

Example:
The first two triangles in the original array
[1, 2, 3] [1, 3, 4]
and when reading from the OpenCL kernel
[1, 2, 3] [3, 4, 0]

Seems OpenCL reads the buffer with different element size / stride than OpenGL. But why?

The OpenGL definition of the buffer:

```
glm::uvec3 triangles;

...

GLuint gl_buffer_id = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &gl_buffer_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_buffer_id);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::uvec3) * triangles.size(), triangles.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Passing the GL buffer to the kernel

```
cl_int err;
cl_mem cl_buffer = clCreateFromGLBuffer(cl_context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, gl_buffer_id, &err);

...

err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cl_buffer);
```

The OpenCL kernel

```
__kernel void my_kernel(
    __global uchar4 * points_color,
    __global uint3 * triangles
    )
{
int pid = get_global_id(0);
points_color[pid] = (uchar4)(triangles[1].x, triangles[1].y, triangles[1].z, 255); // use vertex id as color component
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCL, `uint3` is just an alias for `uint4`, i.e. its size is `4 * sizeof(char)`. See section [6.1.5. Alignment of Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html#alignment-of-types) of the OpenCL specification for more information. You will probably need to use the [vload3](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/vloadn.html) instruction.

> For 3-component vector data types, the size of the data type is `4 *
>   sizeof(component)`. This means that a 3-component vector data type will
>   be aligned to a `4 * sizeof(component)` boundary. The **vload3** and **vstore3**
>   built-in functions can be used to read and write, respectively,
>   3-component vector data types from an array of packed scalar data
>   type.